# Elasticsearch grab all but limit to a certain number with Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

There isnt an example online with the Java API to show how to limit the rows that come back from a search with ElasticSearch for all items.  I tried the Filter Limit but it just wouldnt work because it would bring back more then the limit. I know its per shard to, but is there no way around this.  I cant find the from/size query/filter either in the Java API

```
SearchQuery searchQuery  = startQuery(limit, null).build();
Iterable<Statement> iterableStatements = esSpringDataRepository.search(searchQuery);

if (iterableStatements != null) {
    return IteratorUtils.toList(iterableStatements.iterator());
}

private NativeSearchQueryBuilder startQuery(int limit, QueryBuilder query) {

    NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();

    if(query != null) {
        searchQueryBuilder = searchQueryBuilder.withQuery(query);
    }

    if(limit > 0) {
        searchQueryBuilder = searchQueryBuilder.withFilter(FilterBuilders.limitFilter(limit));
    }
    return searchQueryBuilder;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I got it to work perfectly with this instead of the limit filter:

```
searchQueryBuilder = searchQueryBuilder.withPageable(new PageRequest(0, limit));
```